# Revealing text elements from the top down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a text reveal similar to [this site's main headline](https://www.aristidebenoist.com/), but instead of the text revealing UP from the bottom, I'd like to reveal DOWN from the top.

I've attempted this, which i think is a cool reveal, but I fear I am waaaay off base from the desired result. I feel like I should be attempting to somehow mask and reveal on each span vs. transforming? Any help appreciated!

I am open to jquery, vanilla javascript and/or CSS solutions.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/robbiewhiting/pen/gQqOJo)

html:

```
<div>
  <div class="grid grid-a">
    <h1>
      <span class="grid-item">These Are&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="grid-item">Many Spans&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="grid-item">Of Text&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="grid-item">Each Span&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="grid-item">Of Text&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="grid-item">Should Reveal&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="grid-item">From The Top&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="grid-item">Of Its Own Span&nbsp;</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.grid {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item {
    float: left;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translatey(-500px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.grid-item.is-moved {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: cubic-bezier();
    -webkit-animation: 0.3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
    animation: 0.3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var items = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-a .grid-item')

        // get vendor transition property
        var docElemStyle = document.documentElement.style
        var transitionProp =
            typeof docElemStyle.transition == 'string'
                ? 'transition'
                : 'WebkitTransition'

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i]
            // stagger transition with transitionDelay
            item.style[transitionProp + 'Delay'] = i * 300 + 'ms'
            item.classList.toggle('is-moved')
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position absolute of an direct span child in each grid-item like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.grid-a .grid-item span').each(function(i, x) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(x).animate({ top: 0 }, 1200);
        }, i * 200);
    });
});
```

```css
.grid {
    width: 350px;
}

.grid-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid grid-a">
    <h1>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>These Are&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>Many Spans&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>Of Text&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>Each Span&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>Of Text&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>Should Reveal&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>From The Top&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>Of Its Own Span&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>Not Drop From&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><span>The Top of The Grid&nbsp;</span></div>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Basically, each absolute span starts with `top: -100%`, and you animate it to `top: 0` (where it should be), together with the setTimeout-trick to make all animations happen smoothly.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @JadenBaptista, sorry I posted the answer before seeing the indentation had a lot of tab/spaces misplaced.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!